# Image behind text

Tags: html, css, css-position

I want to display an image behind an H1 tag, I also want the image width to stretch to the same width as the text.

**My code**:

```
<div style="display: inline;">
    <img src="http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/3989/m744.png" width="100%" height="68" />
    <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 0px;">Variable length text</h1>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Aykng/

**Current Appearance**:

[image: Current Appearance]

**Desired Appearance**:

[image: Desired Appearance]

The image width should either stretch or shrink to fill the div, how can I achieve this?

I want it to be compatible with IE 7+, otherwise I would just use `background-image` and `background-size`.

Comment: My production image will be more elaborate, so that's why I can't use a background color.

Comment: why cant you use css `background-image`? seems obvious for your problem

Comment: @x4rf41: I don't want to use `background-size` because it's not compatible with IE <= 8

Comment: it also doesnt work for netscape or aol...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be easily done with some basic positioning added

DEMO **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/Aykng/10/)**

```
div {
    position: relative;
}
h1 {
    display: inline;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Cleanest, simplest answer

Answer (score 3):

this seems to work (also in IE8):

the div will be as big as the `<h1>` (the text is not centered now because of its margins, you have to changed those to make it fit!

```
<div style="display: inline-block;position:relative;">
    <h1 style="position:relative;z-index:2;top:0px;">Variable length text</h1>
    <img src="http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/3989/m744.png" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:68px;z-index:1" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aykng/9/

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way of doing it without using `display: inline-block` and a IE7 hack:

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/3989/m744.png" 
         width="100%" height="68" />
    <h1>Variable length text</h1>
</div>
```

with the CSS:

```css
.parent {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}
.parent img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.parent h1 {
    display: inline;
    position: relative; /* this makes sure the h1 is in 
                           front of img in stacking order */
    border: 1px dotted lightgray;
    padding: 0 10px; /* optional, tweak left/right as needed */
    vertical-align: top;
    line-height: 68px;
}
```

Demo fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/BfMDJ/

This is identical to an earlier solution by [Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2224186/vector) except in how the height of the image is handled.

I chose to set the line height for `h1` to match that of the background image (68px in this example), and then apply `vertical-align: top`.  This makes it easier to vertically align the text if you so desire.

**Potential Issue**

If you set the image width to 100% and set the height, then the image will get distorted.
You would need to specify something about the background image and how you want the text to be centered vertically if you want a more robust answer.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

on the div css.

and place the image as the div's  "background-image".

Comment: Thanks but this would crop the image, not shrink it. It also won't stretch without using `background-size`.

Comment: @Drahcir if thats the case there may be some sort of jquery to help you but im pretty sure you cant do that in css

Comment: and jquery may also not work in ie7+ why-ever in seven hells do you need that compatibility may i ask?

Comment: Because my target audience is lame, they don't upgrade their browsers and have no tech understanding at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. It will work across browsers including IE 7.

```
<div style="display: inline-block;background: url('http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/3989/m744.png') repeat; *display:inline;*zoom:1;">
    <h1>Variable length text</h1>
</div>
```